# Finding all values of $\theta$ which describes a straight line

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions

I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding the below question; my assumption is that I should bring the right-hand side in terms of $\sin \theta$ or $\cos \theta$ however am not able to proceed through. The question is below, I shall keep the question updated shortly with my attempts.

---

[image]

---

Do note that I haven't attempted Question (b) yet, I would prefer if clear hints are given to work (a) out first so that I can attempt (b) further on.

### Attempts so far

Thanks to fellow Maths.SE users.

$$1-2\cos\theta = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow -2cos\theta = -1$$ $$\Rightarrow \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$\Rightarrow \theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}) = 60$$

Comment: What are the powers of $x$ present in the equation of a straight line ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I would say, 1

Comment: don't forget zero!

Comment: Then $\cdots$ ?

Comment: True danimal haha; @ClaudeLeibovici - Not sure, something to do with $x^2(1-2\cos \theta)$ I presume? Since that does not satisfy a straight line

Comment: so can you find a value of $\theta$ that kills that part of the equation?

Comment: I presume ! Go on.

Comment: Well $\cos$ seems to only be ranging between -1..1 and any intermediate value seems to be complex, I would require $cos \theta$ to evaluate to $\frac{1}{2}$, let me try to get that value

Comment: When $\theta = 60$ and $\theta = -60$, can't seem to get any other value that returns $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Remember the periodicity, $2n\pi $ :D

Comment: @Arthur - Damn yea, I'm sure there's a more systematic way to do it, I believe using $2n\pi + \alpha$ or $2n\pi - \alpha$

Comment: @Mann - How would you add each period/cycle/revolution though? Not sure what $n$ is meant to be passed as

Comment: $n$ is any integer .

Comment: @Mann Ah alright, that would make sense, thanks :-)

Comment: $\theta=2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3} \forall n \in Z$

Comment: Could you clarify what the symbol preceding $n$ is? haven't come across it before

Comment: $\forall n \in Z$ means "for all n in Z(integer)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Fucntion $y$ describes strainght line iff coefficient of $x^2$ is $0$, so
$$1-2\cos \theta=0\implies\cos\theta=\frac12$$
From this we get
$$\sin \theta =\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
So, equations of these lines are
$$y=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2x+\frac12$$
(b) Let $y=0$. Discriminant of quadratic equation for $x$ is
$$D=\sin^2\theta+8\cos^2\theta-4\cos\theta$$
And
$$\frac{dD}{d\theta}=4\sin\theta-14\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
Solving $4\sin\theta-14\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$ you will get that minimum value of $D$ is at $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac27+2k\pi$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. At these points $D=\frac37$.

Comment: Hi, I'll be examining your answer in regards to part (b) shortly, thanks for posting :-)

Comment: Not sure how you performed your second step where you put $\sin \theta$, mind clarifying?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable in your equation is $x$ and $\theta$ is a fixed real number (which the statement of your problem fails to specify), then you're looking to get only first or zeroth powers of $x$, as in :

$y = ax + b, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

where $ax$ is the first-power term and $b = bx^0$ the zeroth-power term.

This means that terms of higher power ($x^2$, $x^3$, ... or indeed any term of the form $x^n, n \in [[2, +\infty]]$) need to disappear. Which are these terms in your example ? How can you go about making them be equal zero ?

Comment: Figured out that $1-2\cos\theta$ has to evaluate to 0. This was done through *trial & error* and so the values for $\theta$ that I got were $-300,-60, 60, 300$

Comment: *Figured out that 1−2cosθ has to evaluate to 0.* Yes.
*Trial and error* No, you gotta solve it, this is the whole point ! You should already smell that there's an infinity of solutions anyway (as is often the case with unbounded trigonometric functions), so trial and error like that will never give you them all.

Comment: Yep that is true, I was going to make use of $\cos \theta = 2n\pi \pm\alpha$ but not too sure how to implement it here. Maybe $\cos \theta = 2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$ since 60 was the first value (which then keeps looping depending on $n$ I suppose

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're referring to here. Just calmly work your equation ($Solve\ 1-2cos\ \theta = 0\ for\ \theta \  in\  \mathbb{R}$) step by step.

Comment: $-2\cos\theta = -1 \Rightarrow \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \theta = \cos^{-1} (\frac{1}{2}) = 60$

Comment: Correct for 60 deg / $\frac{\pi}{3}$ rad but that's one answer in a multitude.

Comment: Now as you've presented mentioned, there are an infinite; so how would one go about representing all possible values?

Comment: Well, use a variable part, and specify within which (infinite) bounds you allow it to vary.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example that illustrates what you mean?

Comment: Yes, let's switch to simple arithmetics : $Solve\ x -1\ \equiv\ 0\ [5]\ for\ x\ in\ \mathbb{N}$ Intuitively, the answer is : all multiples of five, plus one. So there's an infinite number of solutions : 1, 6, 11, 16, 21 ... How to write it ? Well, let's decompose this "all multiples of five, plus one", and use a static part (x is basically one) and a variable part (x is basically one, give or take any amount of fives) : $x\ =\ 5n\ +\ 1$ where $n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}$. In your case, you figured out the static part already : $\theta$ is basically 60 deg. By how much can it vary though ?

Comment: Before I go, don't know where you're at, but as with all trigonometric functions, variables are allow to vary by $2\pi$ rad or 360 deg, as many times over as you want. That's your variable part.

Comment: No worries Charles, thank you very much for your time, I was in the middle of another question which is why I did not reply. Will be checking it out again soon enough. I got the basic idea atleast so that's a step forward

Comment: One last thing - there is another possibility for the static part - but I'll let you figure this one out.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again! :-)